# Frobenius endorphism for elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves

In the Pairing for Beginners book, I read:

*Frobenius endomorphism $\pi$* for $E$:

- $\pi : E \rightarrow E, (x, y) \mapsto (x^q,y^q)$
- Note: $\pi$ maps any point $E(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q)$ to $E(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q)$, but the set of points fixed by $\pi$ is exactly the group $E(\mathbb{F}_q)$.

Why is the set of points $\#E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ ?

Comment: What is the question? Which set of points?

Comment: Where did the # come from? That was not part of the statement. The fact that the set of fixed points are precisely those is just a basic fact about fields of positive characteristic.

Comment: If you mean why the second statement is true: A point $(x,y)\in{}E(\mathbb{F}_q) \iff x,y$ are of characteristic $q \iff$ $x^q=x$ and $y^q=y \iff \pi(x)=x$ and $\pi(y)=y$

Comment: the # came from "the set of points fixed by $\pi$ is exactly the group"

Comment: The # means "number of elements in".

Answer (score 0):

You can try with $E : y^2 = x^3-x-2$ over $\Bbb{F}_5$ in http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/

```
    F := FiniteField(5); A<x,y> := AffineSpace(F,2);
    E := Curve(A,y^2-x^3+x+2);
    Points(E);    

    F2<a> := FiniteField(5^2);
    E2 := BaseChange(E,F2);
    P2 := Points(E2); P2;
    #Points(E2)+1;

    Q := P2[2]; Q;
    [Q[1]^5,Q[2]^5] // Frobenius
```

Don't forget to add the point at $\infty$ to obtain a group, equivalently look at

```
     Points(ProjectiveClosure(E))
```